# How to create gganimate scatteroplot based on date column?

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2, gganimate

I have an R data frame as follows:

[image]

And a plot like this:

```
p <- ggplot(dftot, aes(x=V1, y=V2)) +
  geom_point(size=0.1, shape=16, stroke = 0, color = '#1F45FC') +
     geom_point(aes(x=V1, y=V2), data=dftot1, stroke = 0, color = '#FCD71E', size=0.1, shape=16)
```

[image]

I want to create a gganimation with the same data frame but each step in the animation has to be the same scatterplot but by the different dates in the JoiningDate field, there are only 9 different dates and each date has more points than the previous one.

I already tried:

```
p +
transition_states(JoiningDate,
                 transition_length = 2)
```

but just repeat the same plot but without animation.

Comment: Please post a sample dataframe, if you want others to help.